# Using of wildcards in T-SQL for Replace

Tags: t-sql

I am completely aware that MS T-SQL does not support regular expression, but I have a requirement of a similar functionality in my project. I don't have the option of extracting the data, manipulating it externally and re-inserting back into the table, So I am trying to use the SQL REPLACE statement.

My problem is as below: In my SQL table I have a text field which stores something like this: "some characters ^&20^&20^ some characters ^&3^&3^ some characters ^&134^&134^ some characters ^&20^&20^ some characters ^&134^&134^ some characters ... "

Now I try to replace all numbers 1...499 between the ^-characters (like ^&20^&20^ and ^&3^&3^ and ^&134^&134^ etc.) with the same string ^&500^&500^.
How can this be achieved in SQL. Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

You were not clear about what you want to replace the text with. This solution assumes that you are looking to replace numbers less that 500, that look like this: ^&11^ with something else. I created a variable (@replaceTxt) so that you can play around with the results. My solution uses [patternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/).

```
declare @string varchar(8000) =
'blah blah blah... ^&20^&20^ ...my phone number is 555-1234 some characters ^&3000^&3000^ some characters ^&134^&134^ some characters ^&20^&20^... with the same string ^&600^&600^...';
declare @replaceTxt varchar(50) = '555';

select newstring = 
(
select --ps.*,
  case when matched = 1 and 
      (charindex('^', ps.item)*charindex('&', ps.item)*patindex('%[0-9]%', ps.item)) <> 0
    then 
    replace((
      select case when cast(item as int) < 500 then '^&'+@replaceTxt+'^' else '^&'+item+'^' end
      from dbo.PatternSplitCM(ps.item, '[0-9]') 
      where [Matched]=1 for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(8000)'), '^^', '^')
    else item end +''
from dbo.PatternSplitCM(@string, '[0-9&^]') ps
order by ps.ItemNumber
for xml path(''), type
).value('.', 'varchar(8000)');
```

Results:

```
blah blah blah... ^&555^&555^ ...my phone number is 555-1234 some characters ^&3000^&3000^ some characters ^&555^&555^ some characters ^&555^&555^... with the same string ^&600^&600^...
```

edit: included a phone number in the sample data to show that not all numbers are changed with this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and sorry for being not clear. My work environment is MS SQL Server 2012.
The source string looks like the one you used: 
'blah blah blah... ^&20^&20^ ...my phone number is 555-1234 some characters ^&3000^&3000^ some characters ^&134^&134^ some characters ^&20^&20^... with the same string ^&600^&600^...'.
In this string every occurrence of:
'^&[0-9]^&[0-9]^'
'^&[0-9][0-9]^&[0-9][0-9]^' 
'^&[0-9][0-9][0-9]^&[0-9][0-9][0-9]^'
'^&[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]^&[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]^'
shall be replaced with '^&500^&500^'.

Comment: At first I got errors from patternSplitCM (Loop-based Solution / PatternSplitLoop), but there was a wrong carriage return (below ,@String = CASE...)
After fixing that patternSplitCM was free of errors.`

Then tried to combine your solution with patternSplitCM, but now I get the following errors: